# Integral of $\sin(1/x)$ from $0$ to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I am interested in proving that the integral $$\int_0^{\infty} \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) dx$$ does not converge. In particular, I would like to show this by appealing to the small angle property of sine. We know that for sufficiently small $\theta$, $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta.$ Said another way, $$\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \approx \frac{1}{x}\ \text{ as } x \rightarrow \infty.$$ We know that the integral $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{x} dx$$ does not converge. With these two ideas in mind, I am trying to find a way to bound $\int \sin(1/x) dx$ from below by $\int 1/x dx$ for sufficiently large $x$ in order to show that $\int \sin(1/x) dx$ does not converge.

Note: one can appeal to the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ and show this does not converge by observing that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{1} = 1$$ via L'Hopital's rule and since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n$ does not converge, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(1/n)$ does not converge. I would simply like to see this notion applied to its integral analogue!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For every $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, we have

$$\sin(x)\ge\frac{\sin(\pi/2)-\sin(0)}{\pi/2-0}x=\frac2\pi x$$

Indeed, all I did was draw a secant line against the $\sin$ function.  Thus, we have

$$\int_{2/\pi}^\infty\sin(1/x)\ dx\ge\int_{2/\pi}^\infty\frac2\pi\frac1x\ dx$$

which diverges.

---

A visuallization of the inequality:

[image]

Comment: Very nice and thank you for the visualization! So the idea is that the secant line allows us to bound $\sin(x)$ from below by some constant times $x$ and, in order to apply this to our situation, we consider all $x$ such that $$x \geq \frac{2}{\pi}$$, i.e. all $x$ such that $$0 < \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$$ Clearly this includes all $x \in [2/\pi,\infty)$. Hence we can bound the integral of $\sin(1/x)$ from $2/\pi$ to infinity from below by the integral of $1/x$ from $2/\pi$ to infinity times some constant, which diverges.

Comment: Yup.  Cheap and easy too.  If we needed to bound from above, this would've been harder, but you would likely use $\sin(x)\le x$.

Comment: Struggling a bit to understand this. How do we know that the secant provides a lower bound all the way to infinity? How would the method have to be modified if the starting point is 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 8):

As you said, $\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x} \stackrel{x \to \infty}{\to} 1.$ In particular, for $x$ sufficiently large,
$$\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}>1/2,$$
and therefore
$$\sin(1/x)>\frac{1}{2x}.$$

Comment: Ah this was the solution that was escaping me! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers gave you nice direct solutions, but there is a general result lurking here, an analogue of the reasoning in your infinite series example. What you're using there is basically the [limit comparison test for infinite series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test); there is also a [limit comparison test for improper integrals](https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf). The proof technique is just a generalization of Aloizio's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The convergence can be verified simply by the Integral Convergence Test.
OR we can also consider the function as a series and check if it is Uniformly Convergent.